# Accessing data in hdfs in a remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, hadoop

I am trying to access hadoop deployed in a remote machine uisng the WebHDFS API provided by Microsoft (Microsoft.Hadoop.WebHDFS). In order to display content of the HDFS file on a client machine I am using the following code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Hadoop.WebHDFS;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static List<string> listFilesName(string strHadoopUserName, string strDirectoryPath)
{
    //uri to access the hadoop through the web
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://192.168.0.165:50070/");
    List<string> lstFilesName = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        WebHDFSClient hdfsClient = new WebHDFSClient(uri, strHadoopUserName);
        Microsoft.Hadoop.WebHDFS.DirectoryListing directroyStatus = hdfsClient.GetDirectoryStatus(strDirectoryPath).Result;
        List<DirectoryEntry> lst = directroyStatus.Files.ToList();
        foreach (DirectoryEntry var in lst)
        {
            lstFilesName.Add(var.PathSuffix);
            MessageBox.Show(var.PathSuffix);
        }
        return lstFilesName;
    }
    catch(Exception exException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exException.Message);
        return null;
    }
```

This relevant configuration file content is displayed below:

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://192.168.0.165:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site .xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>       
    <value>file:/hadoop/data/dfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/hadoop/data/dfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Both machines are within the same network. When I run the above code I am getting the following error:
an aggregate exception has beeh caught/one or more error occured.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question with copy/paste-ed full text of the actual error message.

Comment: There is no extra error message it said , one or more error occured and when i  made a debug there is "an aggregate exception has been caught"?Can you please help troubleshoot the problem @Grisha thnx